# Regex that checks for specific characters

Tags: java, regex

My problem is that I need to check a string if it only contains any number of the following characters:

- any digit 0-9
- any character from these - + . \ * and a white space

If it contains any other character then the string is not valid and the regex should catch it.

I have tried the following regex but unfortunately, it does not work and I am stuck. `"[^0-9 ,.\\-+*]"`

For example: 1 * 2.4324 should be correct but 1 & 2.3231 should not be
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `^` negates the characters in `[]`, can you give more example of what you are trying to match or not

Comment: Put the hyphen at the end after the asterisk.  Inside brackets, it denotes a range of characters.

Comment: Your regex only matches a single character

Comment: I bet you used it with `.matches()` while you should have used `Matcher#find()`

Comment: BTW division normally is / (slash) and not \ (back-slash) ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for

```
^[0-9 ,.\-+\*]*$
```

This first looks for the beginning of the string `^`, then any number of your allowed characters `[...]*`, and lastly the end of the string `$`. Your regex looked for any one occurence inside your string, so as long as one character was valid, the whole input was matched successfully.

**Update**

Actually, I misread your regex. You have negated the class, therefore matching a single character should have worked. You can find an example here: https://regex101.com/r/bKZAl5/1/

I believe, you may have just misquoted some of your characters. The asterisk should be escaped, and the minus is currently not escaped, giving you a whole matching character range from `\` to `+`. That said, it may need the double backslashes to escape it in your input string, and you just pasted it here as is.

Comment: This solution fails for the expression 1 * 2.4324 which is correct. Do i have to escape any of these characters?

Comment: The regex I provided is actually the inverse of what you are trying to do. You will need to negate your condition for it to work properly. It will match the string ONLY if the input string is valid according to your rules. Your condition was probably that when the regex matches, it will be invalid input. Now, it returns true, when the input is valid.

Comment: You can see here, that the input matches fine with my regex, just the condition is reversed: https://regex101.com/r/SBmekY/1/

Comment: Yes you are right. Your answer is correct. The only thing I wasn't able to do is it to be correct when I use "\". Currently it says that it doesnt match. Which character do I have to escape.

Comment: If you also want backslash to be a valid character, just add it to the character class as '\\'. This would be the correct escaping for the regex itself. If you are specifying the regex in a Java string, you will need to escape both backslashes with another backslash, so '\\\\' would be correct (both cases without the apostrophes!). Escaping can be a real pain :-)

Comment: "asterisk should be escaped" - not sure if that is needed inside `[]`